# MS Access create table from query c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Unable to create table via

```
CREATE TABLE AAA ( 
               [Percentage] Number(15),
               [ID] AutoIncrement CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ,
               [CaseRecNo] Number(15),
               [CaseName] Text,
               [Amount] Currency 
             )
```

Gives Syntax Error,

How to set Number filed type double ?

Answer (score 0):

The field size is a double by default.  Create this table in access and you will see the result.  You also need to name your constraint

```
CREATE TABLE AAAB ( 
           [Percentage] NUMBER,
           [ID] AutoIncrement CONSTRAINT MyFieldConstraint PRIMARY KEY ,
           [CaseRecNo] Number,
           [CaseName] Text,
           [Amount] Currency 
         )
```